# VTC review queue mismatch between flagged reasons overview and close reason counters

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I have encountered the following during the review of questions to be closed:

[image: close mismatch]

The overview indicates three reasons the question was flagged for. Offtopic has sub-options, so it is rather ok (although would be nice to aggregate votes from subitems) not see any vote for it in the main view. However, I expect that "unclear" and "too broad" to have at least 1 close vote next to them, since the overview mentions these reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see in the top bar is a combination of reasons it has been flagged and or close voted for.

What you see in the close box is only the reasons it has been closed voted for.  So, if there are things missing it means the questions was flagged with those options, not closed voted.  This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Close flags will get a question into the close vote queue but they do not count as close votes.  Only 3K+ rep users can close vote and only close votes will close a question.